# apex:actionSupport 'action' was not fired, when apex:selectList controller 'rendered' value got true

Tags: apex-code

When value of `hasMoreCategories` got as `YES`, `apex:selectList` controller is successfully rendered. But that will not execute `loadValuesWithCategor` method that comes under the `apex:actionSupport`. Does anyone have some idea about this issue? Code is as follow.

```
<!-- Panel for display category relate information -->
<apex:outputPanel id="categoryPanel">

  <apex:outputLabel value="Category" rendered="{!hasMoreCategories=='YES'}" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;

  <!-- ControllerSRAndTesting: category -->
  <apex:selectList label="Category" id="categoryList" value="{!categoryValue}" rendered="{!hasMoreCategories=='YES'}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!jobCategorValues}"></apex:selectOptions>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!loadValuesWithCategor}" rerender="itemsReqPageBlock, footer" />
  </apex:selectList> &nbsp;

</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question : can you verify from the debug log that the 'loadValuesWithCategor' method is definitely not being executed when the selection is made?

Without knowing what the rest of your page looks like, it is difficult to know what the problem might be.  You could have a required field on the screen that is not populated with the picklist selection is made and that could cause this type of problem.

Comment: Hi TechOwl! many thanks for your feed back. Yes I have checked with debug logs and it was not executed. Yes my page is bit complicated and it had several 'form' tags etc. But whenever I remove '`rendered="{!hasMoreCategories=='YES'}"`' option from the '`apex:selectList`' it will work perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I my self done some mistake, that is why that code has been behaved like that manner. That mean I have reset the value of `hasMoreCategories` as `NO` within `loadValuesWithCategor` method. Therefore even it was rendered due to value of `rendered` option is `false` , `apex:selectList` component does not existing on the UI. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to call the methode by actionSupport do below task.

1. Remove "transient" from a declaration of a selectoption list.
2. Remove immediate attribute.